# php curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION error

Tags: php, curl

i got an error

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in

i google many solution, but with this site they don't work. only need  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. stupid hoster don't want to enable safe_mode or an open_basedir . can i enable them by myself, may be create htaccess with some parameters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error means safe_mode or open_basedir ARE enabled (probably open_basedir) you probably can't override either if your host has any decent security settings.

So you have a choice

1) change host (not really desirable I imagine)

2) use a function similar to ones found on the php curl_setopt page, i.e. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#95027

The following is a fixed version of the function specified in point 2

```
function curl_redirect_exec($ch, &$redirects, $curlopt_header = false) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302) {
        list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);

        $matches = array();
        preg_match("/(Location:|URI:)[^(\n)]*/", $header, $matches);
        $url = trim(str_replace($matches[1], "", $matches[0]));

        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        if (isset($url_parsed)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $redirects++;
            return curl_redirect_exec($ch, $redirects, $curlopt_header);
        }
    }

    if ($curlopt_header) {
        return $data;
    } else {
        list(, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
        return $body;
    }
}
```

Comment: funny, but script works well on my host (cheap and virtual), but boss use stupid host and don't have desire to change. about this function -i know it, when i start to write script i manually call each url, but last url don't wont to work, and only using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION helps me

Comment: Eek sorry I didn't actually test the function, you're right it doesn't work (it assumes the Location header isn't the last one) I've added a corrected version I tested to my answer.

Comment: Your solution has a few bugs. The regex should be `[^\n]`. When recursively calling `curl_redirect_exec` you should pass `$curlopt_header`.

Comment: Stupid question: How exactly do I use this? When I tried, it said `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference `. I used `$xml = curl_redirect_exec($ch, true);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify that only http and https protocols are allowed during redirect using `CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS`, you would be able to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` without `safe_mode` or `open_basedir`.

Comment: Setting `CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS` to `CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS` doesn't seem to help with `open_basedir` sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i fix adding this condition:

```
$safeMode = @ini_get('safe_mode');
$openBasedir = @ini_get('open_basedir');
if (empty($safeMode) && empty($openBasedir)) {
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
}else
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

and adding in my .htaccess file

```
php_flag safe_mode off
php_flag open_basedir off
```

Comment: Where do your $curl and $curl_handle variables come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given in the below link for an alternative.

http://slopjong.de/2012/03/31/curl-follow-locations-with-safe_mode-enabled-or-open_basedir-set/