# Get final redirected URL

Tags: php, curl

This *specific* URL:

```
https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/3475538/
```

Redirects to:

```
https://chrysanthemumgarden.com/novel-tl/dylm/dylm-71/
```

How do I get the final redirected URL via PHP?

### What I've tried so far

Here's a command line to grab the final URL:

```
curl -Ls -w %{url_effective} -o /dev/null https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/3475538/
```

Doesn't work **with this specific URL**.

Tested PHP version of this and still didn't get the final URL:

```
$url = 'https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/3475538/'; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 

// Return follow location true 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
$html = curl_exec($ch); 

// Getinfo or redirected URL from effective URL 
$redirectedUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 

curl_close($ch); 
echo "Original URL:   " . $url . "<br/>"; 
echo "Redirected URL: " . $redirectedUrl . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Great inclusion of *What I've tried so far*, should be a standard on this site. +1

Comment: Apparently, you are caught by a captcha (from cloudflare) if you try to echo the `$html`.  Hence, you may want to attach the user agent to behave as if you weren't a bot. I tried capturing cookies and I did get them by additionally adding `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` on a temporary basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue. Applying a custom userAgent did the trick for me. 
Thanks to this post: [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002272/curlopt-followlocation-not-working).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

```php
<?php

    $original_url = 'http://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/3475538/';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $original_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");

    $a = curl_exec($ch);
    $url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    echo "Old: ${original_url}\n";
    echo "New: ${url}\n";
```

```
Old: http://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/3475538/
New: https://chrysanthemumgarden.com/novel-tl/dylm/dylm-64/
```

Comment: User agent seems to be necessary because otherwise it considers the request a bot request. I added user agent as `Test redirection` and it still works ok by capturing the cookies, however the `Test redirection` user agent would be banned pretty soon(lol). Hence, user agent like yours simulating like a browser is the best bet. +1