# How to check if website is accessible?

Tags: php

I want to see if a website can be accessed or not with a PHP page.

Here is my plan:

```
<?php 
  $website = /* bool to see if site is up */
  if($website)
{
  echo'<iframe src="http://64.126.89.241/" width="100%" height="100%"/>';  
}else
{
  echo'<iframe src="http://tsiserver.us/backup/" width="100%" height="100%"/>';  
}
?>
```

The website will be hosted on another server, therefore if my internet goes down, a user may access the backup version of a site.

Comment: I think you can use linux function 'curl'

Comment: So, if `$website` is `true`, then it loads `64.126.89.241` or else `tsiserver.us`? What should be defining `$website` in the first place?

Comment: If your server is down, how do you expect PHP to run?

Comment: I think the OP wants to know wether or not a website is accesible via its script

Comment: The domain will be on another server to make sure the main server is up. If not, it will load a "cached" version of the site.

Comment: Thanks to the editor who has eased the pain in my ears (*eyes*). Gawd, don't you just hate it when people "shout"? ;-)

Comment: @GTAWWEKID What exactly is the issue here? It it running, not running as expected, errors, ..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959063/how-to-send-a-get-request-from-php

You could find help here

Comment: Simple: Setup another set of nameservers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607684/curl-and-ping-how-to-check-whether-a-website-is-either-up-or-down -- and here

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It's just a shame he forgot to remove the other fluff and cutesy love-heart BS.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Did I miss the cute love-heart?! OOooohhhhh nooOOoooo.... // oh well, maybe I'll do a rollback. (NOT) ;-) Edit: Just saw that in the edits; aawwww so cute!! lol

Comment: @Aziz Saleh, It is just a hassle to run a email server on Ubuntu, I wanted the main domain on a webhost's server for email, then to point website to my own server to use my mySQL database.

Comment: @GTAWWEKID Add the answer you feel should be marked as the answer as a new answer, not in the question itself.

Comment: @ Aziz Saleh, I must wait 8 hours to do so it says.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function that will determine if a website exists using PHP and cURL

```
function urlExists($url=NULL)  
{  
    if($url == NULL) return false;  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

This was grabbed from [this post](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/05/php-check-if-a-url-exists-with-curl/) on how to check if a URL exists. Because Twitter should provide an error message above 300 when it is in maintenance, or a 404, this should work perfectly.

reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239090/568414

Answer (score 0):

Based on your approach, you would need 3 different servers:

1. The server that hosts the script
2. The server that hosts the website
3. The server that hosts the fallback website

This is not so efficient and many hosting services provide fallback or cached versions of your site in case it's down, automatically. You don't have to mess with a script for this, but if you insist, you can refer to [**PHP's curl manual**](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php).

Comment: It is just a hassle to run a email server on Ubuntu, I wanted the main domain on a webhost's server for email, then to point website to my own server to use my mySQL database.

Comment: In that case you may only want to open your mysql port on the firewall and make it accessible from the webhost, but why wouldn't you just export your database to the webhost?

Comment: Security reasons. The database should not be accessible from anything but localhost.

Comment: If you export your database, it'd still be only accesible for localhost, only that localhost is now another host, but still, your db wouldn't be open to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, thanks guys!

```
<?php 
    function ping($host, $port, $timeout) { 
      $tB = microtime(true); 
      $fP = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 
      if (!$fP) { return "down"; } 
      $tA = microtime(true); 
      return round((($tA - $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms"; 
    }


    $website = ping("64.126.89.241", 80, 10);
    if($website != "down"){
      echo'<iframe src="http://64.126.89.241/" width="100%" height="100%"/>';  
    }else{
      echo'<iframe src="http://tsiserver.us/backup/" width="100%" height="100%"/>';  
    }
?>
```