# Is it possible to find out if the provided website has a re-direct?

Tags: html, ajax

I am trying to build a front end application which will an input text box.

When a user enters an URL in the text field(ex www.google.com, wwww.facebook.com, www.linked.com, etc..), the web app should tell the user whether if the provided address has a re-direction?

Can it be done from ajax?

Comment: AJAX likely won’t be able to request _anything_ for most URLs your users will input, because of CORS not being enabled by many of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting a redirect in jQuery $.ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177252/detecting-a-redirect-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: what if we enable the CORS in our website ?

Comment: you can check using curl. try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607684/curl-and-ping-how-to-check-whether-a-website-is-either-up-or-down)

Answer (score 0):

You can send a GET request to the URL and see what it returns.

Every HTTP response will come with a status code.

You can see the full list of HTTP status codes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

A 301 means the URL has a permanent redirect and a 302 means there is a temporary redirect.