# How to Implement Workaround for CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Tags: php, curl, transfer

Im using this code http://martinsikora.com/how-to-steal-google-s-did-you-mean-feature to do a "did you mean" with my searh but  my hosting provider has open_basedir set and wont leyt me change. I've seen a couple workarounds but I am unaware of how I would implement these to his piece of code.

Here the snippet:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agents[rand(0, count($agents) - 1)]);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the code above has to do with open_basedir?

Comment: Sorry in my code I took out the main problem = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Comment: You cant do followlocation with open_basedir set

Comment: Long-term, the best solution probably will be to find a different web hosting provider that actually knows how to secure their server and doesn't rely on deprecated hacks like PHP safe mode/open_basedir (which have been removed from PHP since 5.4). Or you could move your site to a VPS where you have total control over the hosting environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890631/php-curl-with-curlopt-followlocation-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a bizarre and annoying (and basically undocumented) restriction, especially when it can so easily be worked around. All you need to do is check for `3xx` response codes, then examine the contents of the `Location:` header to find the URL you are being redirected to.

This is not as trivial as one my like it to be as there are many applications that violate the RFC and do not use a full URL as the data in the location header - so you would need to do a bit of fudging to get the right location.

Something like this should work for your code (untested):

```
function make_url_from_location ($oldUrl, $locationHeader) {
  // Takes a URL and a location header and calculates the new URL
  // This takes relative paths (which are non-RFC compliant) into
  // account, which most browsers will do. Requires $oldUrl to be
  // a full URL

  // First check if $locationHeader is a full URL
  $newParts = parse_url($locationHeader);
  if (!empty($newParts['scheme'])) {
    return $locationHeader;
  }

  // We need a path at a minimum. If not, return the old URL.
  if (empty($newParts['path'])) {
    return $oldUrl;
  }

  // Construct the start of the new URL
  $oldParts = parse_url($oldUrl);
  $newUrl = $oldParts['scheme'].'://'.$oldParts['host'];
  if (!empty($oldParts['port'])) {
    $newUrl .= ':'.$oldParts['port'];
  }

  // Build new path
  if ($newParts['path'][0] == '/') {
    $newUrl .= $newParts['path'];
  } else {
    // str_replace() to work around (buggy?) Windows behaviour where one level
    // paths cause dirname to return a \ instead of a /
    $newUrl .= str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($oldParts['path'])).$newParts['path'];
  }

  // Add a query string
  if (!empty($newParts['query'])) {
    $newUrl .= '?'.$newParts['query'];
  }

  return $newUrl;

}

$maxRedirects = 30;

$redirectCount = 0;
$complete = FALSE;

// Get user agent string once at start - array_rand() is tidier
// For these purposes, a single static string will probably be fine
$userAgent = $agents[array_rand($agents)];

do {

  // Make the request
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent]);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  // Get the response code (easier than parsing it from the headers)
  $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  // Split header from body
  $data = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
  $header = $data[0];
  $data = $data[1];

  // Check for redirect response codes
  if ($responseCode >= 300 && $responseCode < 400) {

    if (!preg_match('/^location:\s*(.+?)$/mi', $header, $matches)) {
      // This is an error. If you get here the response was a 3xx code and
      // no location header was set. You need to handle that error here.
      $complete = TRUE;
    }

    // Get URL for next iteration
    $url = make_url_from_location(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL), trim($matches[1]));

  } else {

    // Non redirect response code (might still be an error code though!)
    $complete = TRUE;

  }

// Loop until no more redirects or $maxRedirects is reached
} while (!$complete && ++$redirectCount < $maxRedirects);

// Perform whatever error checking is necessary here

// Close the cURL handle
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what would $locationheaders be I have one url which is 
`$url = 'http://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hl=' . $lang . '&q=' . urlencode($query);`

Comment: @KesiMaduka Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking there - can you elaborate?

Comment: like look at http://martinsikora.com/how-to-steal-google-s-did-you-mean-feature which variables would i put in the function for `$locationHeader` ex: make_url_from_location ($oldUrl, $locationHeader) which variables based on that code would you put in $oldUrl & $locationHeader

Comment: Well the code sample above is designed so that it should just drop into that code, if you just replace everything between `$url = "...";` and `$template_span = '...';` (or `$url = "...";` and `$suggestions = json_decode(...);` depending on which code you use) with the above code and it should work