# curl unable to download webpages

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to open homepages of websites and extract title and description from it's html markup using curl with php, I am successful in doing this to an extent, but many websites are there I am unable to open. My code is here:

```
function curl_download($Url){
     if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $output;
}
// $url is any url
$source=curl_download($url);
$d=new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($source);
$title=$d->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent)
$domx = new DOMXPath($d);
$desc=$domx->query("//meta[@name='description']")->item(0);
$description=$desc->getAttribute('content');
?>
```

This code is working fine for most websites but there are many whome it doesn't even able to open. What can be the reason?

When I tried getting headers of those websites using `get_headers` function, its working fine, but these are not being opened using curl. Two of these websites are `blogger.com` and `live.com`.

Comment: What happens? Any error?

Comment: Just guessing ... are they possibly blocking curl (because curl respects `robots.txt`, or server-side by frowning at curl's request headers)?

Comment: No errors, just returns nothing, I tried opening directly using file_get_contents function, same results, it couldn't.

Comment: curl reacts as if the site doesn't exists..

Comment: i believe these sites require authentication to access

Comment: @ajreal possibly you are right, but in that case, I should have ended up downloading the login or authentication page. A blank result is still weird.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890631/php-curl-with-curlopt-followlocation-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$output) {
   echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

and see why Curl is failing.

It's a good idea to always check the result of function calls to see if they succeeded or not, and to report when they fail. While a function may work 99.999% of the time, you need to report the times it fails, and why, so the underlying cause can be identified and fixed, if possible.

Comment: "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"
This is the error its showing, its about SSL, but i thought curl can handle ssl? other ssl secured sites are responding.

Comment: I had an idea it was a SSL issue. Add this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`. I've updated the answer above.

Comment: wow wow wow, it just worked, great, thankx, if you dont mind, can I follow you on twitter?

Comment: Sure, but I don't tweet much: @rasa7777

Comment: ok, thnx..i just like to be in touch with programmers and business people.