# curl php get data from the next page

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to get data from this site using curl php?

[MyCarInfo](https://www.mycarinfo.com.my/NCDCheck/Online)

I'm using php5 on shared host.

This is what i've so far:

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
    $postData = '';
    //create name value pairs seperated by &
    foreach($params as $k => $v) 
    { 
        $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
    }
    $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$host = "www.mycarinfo.com.my/NCDCheck/Online";

$params = array(
    "VehRegNo" => "TY4484",
    "NRIC" => "821004115453"
);

$url = "https://".$host."/"; 
$NCD = httpPost($url,$params);

var_dump($NCD);
```

The output come out like this:

```
string(173) "
Object moved to here.

"
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here is likely a link in. The PHP response. What is the href value of that link?

Comment: this? https://www.mycarinfo.com.my/NCDCheck/Report?key=vEsbSGcmS2UsAuw%2FRS4v8A%3D%3D

Comment: You could try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` and see if that works for you.

Comment: error: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in

Comment: any other help guys? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890631/php-curl-with-curlopt-followlocation-error) might help?

Answer (score 1):

the website requires that you have a session id cookie and a code called "ssX" that must match before you submit a search, and when those 2 do match, you get a `302 Found` http redirect that you must follow.. you dont obtain a session id cookie, nor an ssX code, nor do you follow 302 redirects. fix those and try again.

using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php , here's a working example code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ();
$hc->_setComfortableOptions ();
// i have a really slow internet connection right now.
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20 
) );
// get a session id cookie, and the weird "ssx" value
$hc->exec ( 'https://www.mycarinfo.com.my/NCDCheck/Online' );
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$matches = array ();
$rex = \preg_match ( '/ssX\s*\=\s*\\\'([^\']*)/', $html, $matches );
// hhb_var_dump($matches);die();
if ($rex !== 1) {
    throw new \RuntimeException ( 'failed to extract the ssX code!' );
}
$ssX = $matches [1];
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                "VehRegNo" => "TY4484",
                "NRIC" => "821004115453",
                'ssX' => $ssX 
        ) ),
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.mycarinfo.com.my/NCDCheck/Online' 
) );
$hc->exec ();
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr(),$hc->getResponseBody() );
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$infoParsed = array ();
$domd = @\DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "table" )->item ( 0 )->getElementsByTagName ( "tr" ) as $tr ) {
    $infoParsed [trim ( $tr->firstChild->textContent )] = trim ( $tr->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->textContent );
}
hhb_var_dump ( $infoParsed );
```

output:

```
HHB_VAR_DUMP_START
in "/home/hanshenrik/workspacephp/phptests2/test.php": on line "38": 1 variable
 hhb_var_dump($infoParsed)
argv[1] >>>$infoParsed<<<:array(7) {
  ["Vehicle Reg. No."]=>
  string(6) "TY4484"
  ["ID Number"]=>
  string(12) "821004115453"
  ["Next NCD Percentage"]=>
  string(3) "30%"
  ["Next NCD Effective Date"]=>
  string(10) "29/12/2016"
  ["Current Policy Period of Cover"]=>
  string(57) "29/12/2015
                -
                28/12/2016"
  ["Current NCD Percentage"]=>
  string(3) "25%"
  ["Current NCD Effective Date"]=>
  string(10) "29/12/2015"
}
HHB_VAR_DUMP_END
```

Comment: thanks @hanshenrik for your effort, i tried this code with no success and lots of error. is there another simpler way or without hhb_curl?

Comment: and seem's like user can use same value of ssX over and over again. eg: ImD1ocFFZcY5krAG0Y6CjEXjGasol/zQJo6LAOjv190=

Comment: @user3613026 most likely, its the same ssX code for the same cookie session id. meaning that every time you get a new cookie session, you probably also get a new ssX code.

Comment: @user3613026 hhb_curl is just a convenience, you can do all the same without it.  but what errors did you get?

Comment: here is the errors:-
Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /home/mysite.com/hhb_.inc.php on line 2

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/mysite.com/hhb_.inc.php on line 4

Comment: @user3613026 oh, you're using PHP5. this code requires PHP7+, oh well, you can use the code as a base for a php5 rewrite though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133718/discussion-between-user3613026-and-hanshenrik).

Comment: @user3613026 i'd rather not, i don't even have a php5 system to test on