# CURL image download

Tags: php, curl

I'm using code which is giving me problems to get a picture using CURL.

```
public function getRemoteFile($url, $dest, $authmode = null, $cookies = null)
{
    $context = $this->createContext($url);
    $ch=$context['curlhandle'];
    $dl_opts = $context['opts']['dl'];
    $outname = $dest;

    if ($cookies)
    {

        if (substr($url, 0, 4) == "http")
        {
            $dl_opts[CURLOPT_COOKIE] = $cookies;
        }
    }

    $fp = fopen($outname, "w");
    if ($fp == false)
    {
        $this->destroyContext($context);
       throw new Exception("Cannot write file:$outname");
    }
    $dl_opts[CURLOPT_FILE] = $fp;
    $this->setURLOptions($url, $dl_opts);
    $this->setAuthOptions($context,$dl_opts);


    // Download the file , force expect to nothing to avoid buffer save problem
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $dl_opts);
    $inf = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if (!curl_exec($ch))
    {
       if (curl_error($ch) != "")
       {
           $err = "Cannot fetch $url :" . curl_error($ch);
       }
       else
       {
           $err = "CURL Error downloading $url";
       }
       $this->destroyContext($context);
       fclose($fp);
       unlink($dest);
       throw new Exception($err);
    }
    else
    {
     $proto=$context['scheme'];
     if($proto=='http' || $proto=='https')
      {
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $ok = ($httpCode < 400);
        if(!$ok)
        {
            fclose($fp);
            @unlink($outname);
            throw new Exception('Cannot fetch URL :'.$url);
        }
      }
    }

    fclose($fp); 
    $this->destroyContext($context);

    return true;
}
```

And I'm getting this output:

> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /usr/home/shop.domain.com/web/productimport/inc/remotefilegetter.php on line 290

I also tried to see what do i get on ***$dl_opts*** Because error starts when I call:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, $dl_opts);
```

So inside ***$dl_opts*** I got:

```
Array ( [80] => 1 [42] => 0 [44] => 0 [52] => 1 [10023] => Array ( [0] => Expect: ) [19913] => [19914] => 1 [10001] => Resource id #261 [10002] => http://domain/picture/static/l0033.jpg )
```

**INFO:**

- PHP 5.3.29
- safe_mode    Off
- open_basedir: /usr/home/shop.domain.com/:/home/shop.domain.com/:/usr/home/services/:/usr/share/php53/

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));

Comment: your error message contains your answer `cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set`

Comment: @DiegoVieira Yes... this is why i pasted info about my phpinfo(). I've to say this is not my code i just have to solve it but i don't know how. how can i unset open_basedir or fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, allowing 301 and 302 redirects with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION would follow redirects to file:// URLs. (found this commit to PHP sources: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/fba290c061027c24e4c8effdba37addd3430c3d4 )

If redirects to file:// URLs are allowed, whoever controls the originally requested URL can make your PHP script fetch a file from your server's local disk instead. A web service that get a URL from an user and shows the contents could then be used to read any file from server's disk that's accessible to PHP.

Solutions:

- Commit shown in above link fixes this issue. Update PHP to fix
- Disable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
- See older question: [php curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890631/php-curl-with-curlopt-followlocation-error)

Comment: That is for php-7.3.0beta2

Comment: It's included in php-7.3.0beta2, but if you click the `...` button after it, you can see it's included in quite a few other releases as well. It's a five-year old commit, after all. What I forgot to mention, it would also have to be compiled with new-enough version of cURL library (7.19.4 or later).